# Glass mapper Editable() with List<> items not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

I have a list of items I'm reading out of sitecore and looping in my View. The items are quite stright forward and are simply output as a series of `<li>`

### Model

```cs
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
public class Model
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string TabText { get; set; }
}
```

I use the model above in a

### Viewmodel

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model> Models {get; set;}
}
```

I'm struggling to consume this view model in my view though and use glassmappers `Editable` feature:

### View

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<ViewModel>
<ul>
    @for (int specCounter = 0; specCounter < Model.Models.Count; specCounter++)
    {
        <!--@specCounter-->
        <li>
            @Editable(e => e.Models[specCounter].TabText)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

this results in a series of errors being written into the resuting HTML:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index
>
> at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument, ExceptionResource resource)    at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   SpecificationInDetailViewModel )    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field,
>   Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context
>   context, Database database, TextWriter writer) Index was out of range.
>   Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

If I remove the `Editable` call then the `<li>` are output correctly. If I use a `foreach` loop (as opposed to a `for` loop):

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<ViewModel>
<ul>
    @foreach (var model in Model.Models)
    {
        <!--@specCounter-->
        <li>
            @Editable(e => model.TabText)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

then **all** the `<li>` contains the text from the last Model (obviously some kind of pass by reference issue). Again removing `Editable` produces the correct result.

Is there any work around for this? I want these items to be editable in the experience viewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass the target Glass Item as a first parameter to the `Editable`:

```
@for (int specCounter = 0; specCounter < Model.Models.Count; specCounter++)
{
    <!--@specCounter-->
    <li>
        @Editable(Model.Models[specCounter], e => e.TabText)</li>
}
```

or `foreach`:

```
@foreach (var model in Model.Models)
{
    <!--@specCounter-->
    <li>
        @Editable(model, e => e.TabText)</li>
}
```

For more information, check [Glass Tutotial - MVC Page Editor Support](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14).